# How can I check if username AND email are already taken in register/signup route?

Tags: mongodb, express

I'm in a React/Express/MongoDB project,
And in my server, in the register route, I succeed to check if email is already taken,
But now I want to check at the same time if the email AND the username are already taken,

My code right now for the email check only (working) :

```
User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ email: "Email already exists" });
    } else {
      const newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
      });
```

And i try to do this for email + username check (not working) :

```
User.findOne(
    {
      $or: [{ email: req.body.email }, { username: req.body.username }]
    },
    function(err, docs) {
      if (docs.length !== 0) {
        if (docs[0].email === req.body.email) {
          errors.username = "Email already exists";
        } else if (docs[0].username === req.body.username) {
          errors.username = "Username already exists";
        }
      } else {
        const newUser = new User({
          email: req.body.email,
          username: req.body.username,
          firstname: req.body.firstname,
          lastname: req.body.lastname,
          sexe: req.body.sexe,
          mobilePhone: req.body.mobilePhone,
          departement: req.body.departement,
          city: req.body.city,
          password: req.body.password
        });
```

The error I got :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

Can someone help me out ? :D

Thanks,

Comment: you are using findOne it does not return array but an object.

Comment: i tried with "find", but it still doesn't work hm

Comment: can you add console.log(err,docs,docs.length) before if cond and check result

Comment: console.log(err) -> null /
console.log(docs.length) -> 2 /
console.log(docs) -> array of 2 objects

Comment: try consoling docs[0] and adding options {lean:true} in query

Comment: ok it's working perfectly now, thanks